# How to declare and instantiate a matrix of arrays

Tags: c#

I am trying to Instantiate a matrix that contains arrays of colors.
But I am doing something wrong.

```
Color[][,] map_clrs = new Color[64][ 8, 8 ];
```

I would like to end up with the following data structure.
I put Color[] first because I assumed it would be the same as when you do it with an `int[,]`

```
{
 { Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64] },
 { Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64] },
 { Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64] },
 { Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64] },
 { Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64] },
 { Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64] },
 { Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64] },
 { Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64], Color[64] }
}
```

**ANSWER : is this correct?**

```
Color[,][] map_clrs = new Color[8,8][];
```

Comment: do you really need to mix up a jagged `[][]` and a multidimensional `[,]` array?

Comment: It seems like you are asking for a 64x8x8 array which seems weird.  Maybe you're using C# in confusion here.  Explain in English what the result should be and that might clarify.

Comment: It could be a 3 dimensional matrix, but I need to be able to extract the last level individually as an array.

Comment: It's for marching squares. so the matrix is for a X and Y grid and the array will be the array of colors extracted from a spritesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Color[][,] map_clrs = new Color[64][,];
for(var i = 0;i<64;i++)
{
    map_clrs[i] = new Color[8,8];
}
```

And for the inverse:

```
Color[,][] map_clrs = new Color[8,8][];
for(var i = 0;i<8;i++)
{ 
    for (var j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
         map_clrs[i,j] = new Color[64];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply @Joel Coehoorn, But I didn't explain it well. the order is inverted. So the matrix contains arrays of colors in each point. I have adjusted my question.